# mysql суммирование элементов по дате

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте! В бд хранится информация о платежах (дата и сумма платежа), например:

```
  datetime = 1458816701, sum = 1980.00
```

Имеется простой запрос, с помощью которого получаю все данные за определенный период:

```
  SELECT sum, datetime FROM payments  WHERE datetime between '$before' and '$after'
```

Как можно просуммировать все значения `'sum'` по каждому дню? Чтобы не было повторяющихся дней. Как при этом должен выглядеть запрос

Comment: `group by date(from_unixtime(datetime))`, ну и `sum()` конечно применить. а лучше не храните дату-время в секундах, а храните в поле типа date, тогда переводов from_unixtime не понадобится

Comment: @Mike, спасибо огромное!